# Unable to run spring boot 3 with kafka-avro-serializer

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, confluent-schema-registry, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I have a spring boot application in clean architecture.
I use spring boot 3.0.5 with spring-kafka and kafka-avro-serializer :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--    messaging confluent -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
            <version>7.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

The Parent project contains several modules including the module that contains the main class.
Here’s what I put in the parent pom:

```
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>native</id>
            <build>
                <pluginManagement>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                            <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                            <executions>
                                <execution>
                                    <id>build-image</id>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>compile-no-fork</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </execution>
                            </executions>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </pluginManagement>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

Here’s what I put in the pom of the module which contain Main Class:

```
  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

My configuration of spring-kafka  :

```
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      auto-offset-reset: earliest #consume from the beginning of the topic partition
      group-id: myApp
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
    producer:
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
    properties:
      specific.avro.reader: true
      value.subject.name.strategy: "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicRecordNameStrategy"
      auto.register.schemas: true
      enable.idempotence: true
    bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
    properties:
      schema.registry.url: http://localhost:8090
```

image generation goes well but when I execute the image I have an error.

When i Run executable generated i had this error :

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry'
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356)
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:934)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:587)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293)
        at com.bforbank.tokens.ApplicationLauncher.main(ApplicationLauncher.java:19)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:830)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:666)
        at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createRawConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createKafkaConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:451)
        at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createConsumerWithAdjustedProperties(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:427)
        at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createKafkaConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:394)
        at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:371)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.<init>(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:862)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer.doStart(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:381)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.start(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:555)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.doStart(ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.java:231)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.start(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:555)
        at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.startIfNecessary(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:383)
        at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.start(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:328)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178)
        ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
        at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer.configure(KafkaAvroDeserializer.java:48)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:718)
        ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value io.confluent.kafka.serializers.context.NullContextNameStrategy for configuration context.name.strategy: Class io.confluent.kafka.serializers.context.NullContextNameStrategy could not be found.
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseType(ConfigDef.java:744)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef$ConfigKey.<init>(ConfigDef.java:1172)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.define(ConfigDef.java:152)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.define(ConfigDef.java:172)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.define(ConfigDef.java:211)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.define(ConfigDef.java:373)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.define(ConfigDef.java:386)
        at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.baseConfigDef(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.java:277)
        at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.<clinit>(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.java:47)
        ... 29 common frames omitted
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Spring for Apache Kafka or Spring Boot. `Class io.confluent.kafka.serializers.context.NullContextNameStrategy could not be found. at` - it looks like you need a reflection hint for that class.

Comment: Btw, schema registry defaults to run on 8081, but 8090

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. The problem was with another dependency pulling in an older version of `kafka-schema-serializer`

`kafka-avro-serializer:7.3.3` depends on `kafka-schema-serializer:7.3.3` which has the required `io.confluent.kafka.serializers.context.NullContextNameStrategy` class, this class was introduced in v7

I would recommend generating a full project dependency graph, it'll show what's being pulled by what, very helpful is troubleshooting issues like this.

Comment: `I would recommend generating a full project dependency graph` How did you go about doing this?

Comment: Build tools like gradle/sbt have either build-in commands for this or have plugins that enable you to generate a dependency graph. You would typically get an HTML page you can browse and see all dependency relationships.